# How can I backup my keyring?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, gnome-keyring

I'm currently using Linux Mint 17.1 and I would like to backup all my passwords that I store in my keyring on a LUKS encrypted external drive.

But I would like to know, which files I have to copy to have a full backup of my keyring or is there something like an export option I can use?